# Fourier cosine series for $\cos(\pi x)$ on $(0,1)$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

My goal is to find the Fourier cosine series for $f(x) =\cos(\pi x)$ on the interval $(0,1).$

Using the formulas 
$$A_{0}=\frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^{L}f(x)\ dx \ \ \ \  \text{and} \ \ \ \  A_{n}= \frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}f(x) \cos\left(\frac{n \pi x }{L}\right) \ dx,$$
we can find the coefficients to write the series in the form 
$$f(x)\sim \frac{A_{0}}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\cos\left(\frac{n \pi x }{L}\right).$$
I won't write out the calculus and the algebra that follows, but both coefficients come out to be $0.$ Does it make sense for the Fourier cosine series of this function to be equal to $0$?  Was it obvious from the beginning?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A_1$ is not zero:
$$A_1 = \frac{2}{1} \int\limits_0^1 \cos \pi x \cos \pi x \ dx = 1$$
which makes sense because you are approximating the first term of the cosine series including in the Fourier expansion. You are right with the others, $A_0,A_2,\ldots A_{\infty}$
$$A_0 =  \int\limits_0^1 \cos \pi x \ dx = 0$$
$$A_k =  \frac{2}{1} \int\limits_0^1 \cos \pi x \cos \pi x \ dx = 0 \qquad k \geq 2$$

Comment: Thanks so much.  Do you usually always have to calculate the first term?

Comment: You are welcome. Of course, it is a term like any other.